# Random Forest regression and MSE

Tags: regression, random-forest, mse

Is there a reason why the most popular criterion for node splitting is MSE?

Why can't we use RMSLE (Root Mean Square Logarithmic Error), for example?

Answer (score 1):

To check the performance of a split, as you mentioned MSE and RMSE are the popular approaches.

RMSLE penalizes an under-predicted estimate greater than an over-predicted estimate

[image]

*ϵ* is the RMSLE value (score) *n* is the total number of observations in the (public/private) data set, *pi* is your prediction, and *ai* is the actual response for *i*. *log(x)* is the natural logarithm of *x*.

Ref:

https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/RootMeanSquaredLogarithmicError
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110610/86202