# How can I get RMSE from RMSLE

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear

Is that correct If I take e^RMSLE will the resulting value give me RMSE or I am missing sometihing . I want to interpret RMSE from RMSLE

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56658/how-do-you-interpret-rmsle-root-mean-squared-logarithmic-error Best!